# facebook php sdk saves all '5's to mysql database fields instead of data

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Following this tutorial http://www.skwebdesigner.com/?p=586
Below is an excerpt from my fbconnect.php code.

```
if($user){
    // Get logout URL
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
    // Get login URL
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email, user_about_me',
        'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
        ));
}

if($user){

    try{
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    //Connecting to the database. You would need to make the required changes in the common.php file
    //In the common.php file you would need to add your Hostname, username, password and database name!
    mysqlc();

    $name = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['name'], "text");
    $email = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['email'], "text");
    $gender = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['gender'], "text");
    $bio = GetSQLValueString($user_profile['bio'], "text");
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM newmember WHERE email = %s",$email);
    $res = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
    {
        $iquery = sprintf("INSERT INTO newmember values('',%s,%s,%s,%s,'yes')",$name,$email,$gender,$bio);
        $ires = mysql_query($iquery) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile['email'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
    }
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            $user = NULL;
        }

}
}
?>
```

Connects to Database correctly but save facebook information as 5 for every field. Also note, it was saving 1's to every field earlier today.

**What I've tried**

changed $user to $user_profile

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that your 'sprintf' for the insert needs quotes around the %s's.  You can check this by printing $iquery.